# OpenThread API: undefined reference to otThreadGetMaxAllowedChildren()

Tags: nrf52, openthread

I have the problem with compilation. After adding function call
**otThreadGetMaxAllowedChildren()** in the `openthread/examples/apps/cli/main.c` I got an error:

```
openthread/examples/apps/cli/main.c:228: undefined reference to `otThreadGetMaxAllowedChildren'
```

Similary, the same issue with **otThreadGetChildInfoByIndex()**:

```
openthread/examples/apps/cli/main.c:204: undefined reference to `otThreadGetChildInfoByIndex'
```

I have added `-DOPENTHREAD_FTD=1` flag, but error still occurs.

Any idea what should I do to make compilation successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`otThreadGetChildInfoByIndex()`](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/434e6bbffc26a5eef1f5e4f5733b8bd536c250a6/src/core/api/thread_ftd_api.cpp#L265) is only available for FTD builds.

You should either:

1. Disable MTD and RCP in your build options, or
2. Wrap your child table code with `#if OPENTHREAD_FTD`.

You can refer to the [CLI code](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/434e6bbffc26a5eef1f5e4f5733b8bd536c250a6/src/cli/cli.cpp#L832) for example usage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me how to disable MTD and RCP in build options?

Comment: If you are using the convenience makefiles in [`examples/`](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples), you can look for `configure_OPTIONS`. Remove mentions of `--enable-mtd` and `--enable-radio-only`.

Comment: Great :) Thank you very much. I have solved my problem by adding `#ifdef OPENTHREAD_FTD`, nevertheless it is valuable information :)